# Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Not Reflecting Gemfile Update Without Manual Instance Termination

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, deployment, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm facing an issue with Elastic Beanstalk where an initial deployment failed due to a Ruby gem issue. I resolved the issue by updating the Gemfile, but subsequent attempts to deploy the new version do not reflect the changes. The only way I've managed to make the new deployment take effect is by manually terminating the instances and starting fresh ones.

Questions:

1. What might be causing the new deployment not to take effect without manually terminating instances, especially after fixing the initial Ruby gem issue?
2. Is there a recommended or standard process to ensure that Gemfile updates are reflected in Elastic Beanstalk deployments without the need for manual instance termination?
3. Are there alternative approaches or solutions to make the new deployment take effect without terminating instances?